# Android: Frame Layout - ImageView height won't fit

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have a Frame Layout with an ImageView and a TextView inside it. I plan to make that text in the center of the picture.
The problem is that **the image won't fit, the ImageView won't wrap the height of the content good**. Look at the picture:
[image]

I need it to look like this:
[image]

I tried mixing the height and with (wrap content and match parent) but the picture still won't fit well.
This is the xml:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/tvrdjava"
            android:id="@+id/imageView3" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

The picture is in different drawable folders for different resolutions (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi).

Comment: Why not using a RelativeLayout for the ImageView and TextView?

Comment: U can use the android:background="@drawable/your_image ..

Comment: Because I cannot put the text on the picture. @MatPag

Comment: android:background= ... stretches the image for some reason. @RavindraKushwaha

Answer (score 2):

You should try with something like this, using a RelativeLayout instead

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ok"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="TextView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This kind of worked. This frame layout is in a LinearLayout (vertical) and it worked for some reason. Thank you anyways Mat!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MatPag for the idea. Putting this frame layout in a LinearLayout (vertical) worked.

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tvrdjava"
            android:id="@+id/imageView8"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />

        <TextView
            android:text="TrTemp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
             <FrameLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homepage_background_imageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/background_homepage"/>

            </FrameLayout>
```